# How far should one take #ifdef statements for hardware flexibility

Tags: c, coding-style, arduino, embedded

As I understand it, one of the best ways to include different options for different hardware in an embedded systems program is `#ifdef` statements. Stylistically, how far should this go? I guess specifically, would you shake your head if someone uses an `#ifdef` on a function deceleration?

It feels quite silly to me, but one hardware option needs different types of function arguments than another option. Is there a cleaner way to achieve that effect, or is it better to use suboptimal code for some hardware options?

If that's too much text to read and you prefer code:

```
#ifdef internaldac
    int dacWrite(int level) {
#else 
    int dacWrite(byte highbyte, byte lowbyte) {
#endif
```

I think this is the most efficient way to write this, but should I be doing it another way (stylistically)?

Comment: This seems like a huge hassle, since every time you call the function you will have to make the same case distinction. Have you thought about using a wrapper around that function that abstracts this hardware detail away from the rest of your code? After compilation, this wrapper would consist of a single function call and the runtime overhead should be negligible.

Comment: "best ways to include different options for different hardware" is very vague and "what's best" is not obvious. This will be different from case to case basis. Compiler switches, downloading different programs, designing the program to support different hardware, storing configurations in NVM, retrieving configurations from some external source... etc etc.

Comment: It was absolutely a stylistic and subjective question, as the code was running as I intended it to. It just felt wrong and didn't make me happy, so I was looking for alternative ways to do it. I think I'll leave it alone because I got an excellent answer. I will refrain from asking for a "best" solution of this type in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL).  The code within the HAL encapsulates all the hardware specific differences.  The higher level code that calls into the HAL should not be aware of any hardware specific differences because the HAL has abstracted those details into a more generic interface.

Your example does not abstract the difference but rather passes the differences along to the higher level code in the form of different parameters.  The higher level code will need to check the hardware type so that it can make the appropriate call to `dacWrite()`.

As an alternative, consider how you can abstract both `int level` and `byte highbyte, lowbyte` into a more generic parameter that is hardware independent.  Then the higher level code that calls `dacWrite()` doesn't need to know what hardware it is running on.  Instead, `dacWrite()` will take care of the details.

I'm not sure whether this is technically correct for your situation but here is an example.

```
    int dacWrite(int level) {
#ifdef internaldac
        byte highbyte = (level >> 8) & 0xFF;
        byte lowbyte = level & 0xFF;
#endif 
    ...
    }
```

Comment: even then you shouldn't use `#ifdef` -- ideally the build system should select the correct variant for the target platform.

Comment: Thank you! I have worked with large projects with a HAL before, but I had trouble applying the concepts to a small (arduino) project, especially after having started with somebody else's code. But that was an excellent explanation, and I feel a lot more comfortable with this now!

Answer (score 0):

Method of code division I used (probably there are more):

- #ifdef inside method - declaration is not divided
- #ifdef with different arguments - as yours above
- different method names one file and #ifdef in one file to divide
- same method name and filename but different location of file (folder, catalog)
- different method name different filename

If there are a lot of calls for dacWrite in shared code, it will be nice if you could wrap it in such a way, that newDacWrite call could be used without #ifdef.

Answer (score 0):

It's often convenient to use the same binary to cover hardware variants. For example, production is more straightforward, and if you have some kind of firmware upgrade system it's simpler.

That means wrting your DAC function so that it dynamically determines the type of hardware and behaves accordingly, taking args that are suitable for either type.

The rest of the code is then independent of the hardware type.